# Searching for a value in a TriTree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, search, tree

I recently just started learning Haskell and I am trying to implement a function for searching for a specific value in a tri tree which returns true if the value is present and false otherwise. This is how my type looks:

```
data TriTree a
  = Empty
  | NodeOne a (TriTree a) (TriTree a) (TriTree a)
  | NodeTwo a a (TriTree a) (TriTree a) (TriTree a)
  deriving (Show)
```

This tree basically is empty or which contains at least one Internal Node. In which each Internal Nodes store one or two data values as well as have max three child nodes (left, middle, right).

It's not clear to me how to proceed with the search function to traverse through the tree and return the value.

Comment: What is a tri tree?  Is it just any tree that happens to have nodes with three children, or are there specific guarantees about the node contents, like an ordering guarantee?

Comment: As defined, `NodeOne` has three children. I would have expected only two, if this kind of tree is similar to a search tree.

Comment: derive `Traversable`, then `\v -> getFirst . getConst . traverse (Const . First . (\x -> [x | x == v]))` or something (using MonadCoprehensions). e.g. [running this for `v == 1`](https://replit.com/@WillNess1/FragrantFlawedSequences#Main.hs) over `[2,1]++undefined` returns `Just 1`.

Comment: @WillNess [`find`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:find) implements that pattern.

Comment: @DanielWagner ah thanks, interesting. `Const` was superfluous here... so, is it always superfluous? can't we always fold into that same Monoid directly (like `find` does)? every Traversable must be Foldable anyway. am I missing something?

Comment: @WillNess I guess every `Traversable` is `Foldable`, but not every traversal comes from `traverse`. [`HashMap.traverseWithKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.19.1/docs/Data-HashMap-Internal.html#v:traverseWithKey) comes to mind; there is a `foldrWithKey` but no `foldMapWithKey` available from the official API. And, of course, traversals are not the only use for `Const`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you defined a recursive data structure, it makes sense to have a recursive function to parse it. To do that I'd start with anchoring the recursion in the trivial case. Since an empty tree doesn't contain anything, the check will always be false:

```
elem' _ Empty = False
```

Now to the recursive part: In the case of a `NodeOne`, we need to check if the value is inside that node or in any of the subtrees of that node, so we check if

```
elem' x (NodeOne v a b c) = x == v || x `elem'` a || x `elem'` b || x `elem'` c
```

The remaining case is for `NodeTwo` and I leave that for you to figure out, which shouldn't be difficult to as it is just a generalization of the line above:

```
elem' x _ = undefined -- remaining case
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZA7D8IwDIT3/IobkGgGBp5b2WCEge4QGgMRbYpCeUn978Xh0VIJJJbI9vl8n7JTxz0lSVlqlStEzkSOCEoAISbpIb9xVWCWaZpbniOoVuSvunJEl4wd/3o0OXM2dotgscsuUghBCaVtLJ8czDNVyZFe0yuCN9SZI9aIJW9cEYbcFwVXq8fiisVGu262cXVvyf6T1bQxljQ6HThKlbGeKFacK3KPGlZ/0a0Jei/Ej1fWav@n6j9ogOEXXfhoDgsOztgcLT7yJvYYEuNxrY2aWlneAQ)