# Searching through a TrinaryTree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, pattern-matching, nodes, programming-languages

I am trying to search through a TriTree.

I have this type for my Tree and here's my search function for NodeTwo:

```
data TriTree a
  = Empty
  | NodeOne a (TriTree a) (TriTree a) (TriTree a)
  | NodeTwo a a (TriTree a) (TriTree a) (TriTree a)
  deriving (Show)

search :: Ord a => a -> TriTree a -> Bool
search _ Empty = False
search x (NodeOne v a b c) = x == v || x `search` a || x `search` b || x `search` c
search x (NodeTwo u v a b c) = x == u || x == v || x `search` a || x `search` b || x `search` c
search x _ = undefined
```

Someone else had the same question; we're given the type but need to implement search. Is the search function I implemented for NodeTwo is valid? Is it even pattern matching if this doesn't handle both NodeOne and Node two within one call?

Comment: Unfortunately the original question was deleted by its OP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72007419

Answer (score 2):

By the time you write `search x _ = undefined` you have matched all possible  cases already, so this is unnecessary. Your compiler should warn you that the pattern is redundant.

Otherwise this appears to work quite well. To my eye you've done this the right way using pattern-matching to handle `TriTree` values constructed using `Empty`, `NodeOne`, or `NodeTwo`.

These three clauses do belong to one and the same function definition, so they do handle all three possible cases "within one call". This can be seen clearer when re-written as the equivalent one `case ... of ...` expression.